# Tagging: Wi-Fi or WiFi?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We currently have a [wi-fi](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wi-fi) tag. This seems unnatural to me - I've always written WiFi. There's precedent for [wifi](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) - Super User has [wifi-configuration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wifi-configuration) and [wifi-driver](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wifi-driver), Server Fault uses [wifi](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wifi), and Apple uses [wifi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi). I stopped looking after that.

Should we have [wifi](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) instead, or do people like the hyphenated form?

Answer (score 4):

It's better to be consistent. Keep the [wifi](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) and get rid of the [wi-fi](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wi-fi).

Answer (score 3):

I noticed this a while back and I looked it up. The official way to write it is "Wi-Fi" (with capitals and all, see [this](http://tsdr.uspto.gov/documentviewer?caseId=sn75799629&docId=IPC20070420145537#docIndex=19&page=1) and [this](http://www.wi-fi.org/who-we-are)), but as you said, "wifi" is much more common nowadays. It's essentially becoming a [genericized trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks).

So [wifi](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) would definitely be better than [wi-fi](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wi-fi).

Comment: Do you have a reference for the 'official' way? I wasn't able to find anything remotely official for it. Just curious ;)

Comment: @Undo [This](http://tsdr.uspto.gov/documentviewer?caseId=sn75799629&docId=IPC20070420145537#docIndex=19&page=1) shows the hyphenation, and [this](http://www.wi-fi.org/who-we-are) shows the capitalization (and also hyphenation).

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thank you!